# CoffeeScript a = +a

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I'm debugging through someone else's code and I found this snippet:

`req.body.address.id = +req.body.address.id`

My first thought was that this had to do with making a negative number positive, but it doesn't do that. The address id's in question here should always be numbers, and adding a `+` in front of a number doesn't seem to do anything.

Would anyone know why you'd do this?

Comment: Are they numbers or are they numeric strings?

Comment: The answers are both similar and correct. On a side note - I'd use `Number(numericValue)` over `+numericValue` to convert something to a number because it's more explicit about what it's doing. Had you seen `Number(value)` in the code, you'd know immediately what it does. Just like I prefer `Boolean(val)` over `!!val`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The unary `+` operator converts the operand to a number. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#-_.28Unary_Plus.29):

> The unary plus operator precedes its operand and evaluates to its operand but attempts to converts it into a number, if it isn't already.

For example:

```
var a = '1';
console.log(a);  // "1"
console.log(+a); // 1
```

So yes, it has no effect on numbers, but if you provide it a non-numeric value, it's useful for safely converting it to a number.

Answer (score 2):

The [unary `+` operator](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.6) will perform type conversion, forcing the value `ToNumber()`, if necessary:

```
var foo = '1';
var bar = +foo;

console.log(typeof foo, foo + 2); // 'string' '12' (concatenates)

console.log(typeof bar, bar + 2); // 'number' 3 (adds)
```